# Async function missing a return statement?

Tags: typescript, async-await

I just finished writing the following method for a bug I'm working and was wondering why the compiler did not complain about the following function having the possibility of not returning? If I instead write `if (false)` the compiler immediately complains about not all paths returning a value.

What happens if `if (data && data.json().length)` is false? Does this function return anything?

```
private async getData(items: any[]): Promise<number> {
    for(const item of items) {
        let data = await item.promise;
        if (data && data.json().length) {
            return data.json().findIndex(d => d.fqdn);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[Section 6.3 of the TypeScript spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#63-function-implementations) explains this (emphasis added):

> An explicitly typed function whose return type isn't the Void type, the Any type, or a union type containing the Void or Any type as a constituent **must have at least one return statement somewhere in its body**. An exception to this rule is if the function implementation consists of a single 'throw' statement.

Your function has one reachable return statement, so it satisfies this requirement. If you place the `return` inside an `if (false)`, it isn't considered, because it is unreachable.

In the event that it terminates without explicitly returning, it will implicitly return a promise for `undefined`, which is an allowed value for `Promise<number>` when the `strictNullChecks` option is not enabled.

This is unrelated to `async`. The following also compiles without error:

```
function getData(): number { 
    if (1 + 1 === 3) {
        return 7;
    }
}
```

As does this:

```
function getData(): number { 
    if (1 + 1 === 3) {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

> What happens if if (data && data.json().length) is false? Does this function return anything?

It returns a promise that resolves to `undefined`, because it is marked as `async`, and `async` functions always return promises.

Note that (as Tom Fenech pointed out before me), using the strictNullChecks causes both your function and the ones in this answer to produce compiler errors, because `undefined` is not considered to be a possible value of `number` when that option is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions always return a promise. In case of `if (false)` TypeScript compiler complains, because `return` statement is unreachable. The function returns a promise of `undefined` in this case. This also happens if `data && data.json().length` is false, but this problem cannot be detected by the compiler.

The function doesn't require explicit `return` at the end of the function if it has no default value to return, but it should be typed accordingly:

```
private async getData(items: any[]): Promise<number|void> {
    for(const item of items) {
        let data = await item.promise;
        if (data && data.json().length) {
            return data.json().findIndex(d => d.fqdn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't care if the function returns a promise of `undefined` (unless `strictNullChecks` are enabled, which they aren't in OP's case). It cares whether the function has at least one (reachable) `return` statement that returns a type that can be coerced into `number` or `Promise<number>`. You can observe this by replacing the `return` statement in OP's example with `return undefined`.

Comment: I believe strictNullChecks should be assumed in any recent TS answer, but it doesn't matter here. I updated the answer to make it clear that *function returns a promise of undefined* is not a consequence of *return statement is unreachable*. TypeScript doesn't care about that, but a user does. The point is that Promise<number> is not correct type for a function that can potentially return a promise of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The function always returns a Promise. In the case that the function implicitly returns, the Promise will resolved to undefined.

With `strictNullChecks` enabled, this should result in a compiler error.

You can see this in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=async%20function%20a(i%3A%20boolean)%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(i)%20return%205%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) (try toggling `strictNullChecks` in the options):

```
async function a(i: boolean): Promise<number> {
    if (i) return 5;
}
```

You can also remove the `async` keyword and change the return type to `number` and you will see the same behaviour.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the function always returning a promise, but it's true that `strictNullChecks` causes it to have a compiler error.

Comment: I'm not saying it is behaviour specific to the `async` keyword, I just used the same types as in the question. I have edited to make that explicit.

Comment: Ok, but in OP's example, the function body is actually returning (as far as the compiler knows) `any`. It has no way of determining what type `data.json().findIndex(d => d.fqdn)` is.